# Rails 4 with turbolinks, embedded gists do not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, pjax, gist, turbolinks

When trying to embed a gist and then accessing a page through turbolinks it's just empty and nothing shows up.

When accessing the same page with a full reload then it works.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: mind showing some code?

Comment: There really is no code to show. It's just a script that points to the gist. The url is provided by github in the "embed gist" shortcut.

I also tried to manually supply the data tag for enabling turbolinks in scripts but I'm pretty sure that only works when the script tag is in the head of the document.

For example, I just put this url in my article (replacing foobar and 123 with the real values of course):
<script src="https://gist.github.com/foobar/123.js"></script>

Then it fails to load the gist by not showing it on the page and there are no warnings or errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new file e.g `gist.js.coffee` and in it add the following coffee script

```
$ ->
  loadGists()
  $(document).on 'page:load', loadGists

loadGists = ->
  $('.gist').each ->
    loadGist $(this)

loadGist = ($gist) ->
  callbackName = 'c' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)

  window[callbackName] = (gistData) ->
    delete window[callbackName]
    html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + encodeURI(gistData.stylesheet) + '"></link>'
    html += gistData.div
    $gist.html html
    script.parentNode.removeChild script

  script = document.createElement 'script'
  script.setAttribute 'src', [
    $gist.data('src'), 
    $.param(
      callback: callbackName
      file: $gist.data('file') || ''
    )
  ].join '?'
  document.body.appendChild script
```

Next, change all of your gist script tags into divs with a gist class and data attributes for the URL and the file name. Also, use the .json extension instead of .js.

```
<!-- before -->
<script src="https://gist.github.com/username/gist_id.js"></script>
<script src="https://gist.github.com/username/gist_id.js?file=file_name"></script>

<!-- after -->
<div class="gist" data-src="https://gist.github.com/username/gist_id.json"></div>
<div class="gist" data-src="https://gist.github.com/username/gist_id.json" data-file="file_name"></div>
```

That should solve your issue. See the full tutorial I wrote about [using github embedded gists with turbolinks](http://goo.gl/h4oMLX)

Answer (score 0):

From Turbolinks' documentation:

> Turbolinks will evaluate any script tags in pages it visits, if those
>   tags do not have a type or if the type is text/javascript. All other
>   script tags will be ignored.

So it looks like by putting `<script src="gist.github.com/foobar/123.js"></script>` in your returned html, turbolinks attempts to evaluate it instead of just displaying its contents.
Try embedding it with the other link instead (`https://gist.github.com/xxx/yyyyy`)

Comment: What do you mean by embedding it with the other link? Wouldn't just putting in the url without script tags simply link to the gist as a standard html link?